# uploading files to the php server from java applet while using digital signature for authenticity

Tags: java, php, digital-signature, backend

I am developing an major project for my undergraduate degree.
I have an java applet that is encrypting a file using aes algorithm. The file is then stored in local machine. Now I want to store that file in my MySQL database at server. I am using php at backend. I also want to verify that file by using digital signature. I wrote some java code that generates a signature and public key file and some code to verify that signature for the given file. 
The problem is suppose multiple users are accessing that page and for every instance these files will be generated and stored in their respective local machines.
I don't know how can I upload these files to the server and verify individual users.
Is there any better way of doing this.

Comment: It is the problem is suppose there are 10 users accessing that page simultaneously then tere will be 10 signature files 10 public key files and then data files that will be uploaded to server. And how to verify the signature at the server.

Answer (score 0):

With Applet you can get the Client IP Address. First send a POST Request to your PHP Web Application with the IP and Public Key. Store these in a data structure.

Then Upload the file using another POST Request from the Upload Script you can find the IP and  retrieve the public key for that IP from the datastructure.

**UPDATE**

Don't forget to Encrypt then Encode the Public Key before sending through the POST Request if you don't use HTTP over SSL.